# React counter state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter, react-state

I am having trouble in updating a counter state in React. To clarify things - I am using 2 states, one is a counter, the other one is an id-counter(basically the same idea and structure). In my render jsx I've got this:

```
<button onClick={incCounter}></button>
<button onClick={decCounter}></button>
<button onClick={addItem}></button>
```

The reason I am including the **incCounter** and **decCounter** is because I am confused how they work properly, and the ID counter does not. Here is the code:

```
const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemsContext)

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

const [id, setId] = useState(0)


const incCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1)
}
const decrementQuantity = () => {
    setCounter(counter - 1)
}
```

Here is the problematic part which does not work for some reason(id always has the value of 0):

```
const addItem = () => {
    
    if (!(items.some(item => item.name === props.name))) {
        setId(id + 1)
        setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, { id: id, name: props.name}])
    }
}
```

Note: I tried moving **setId** above the **if** statement, no result.

Comment: I think it should be `setId(prevState => prevState+1)` (You need to access and increase previous state value instead of directly accessing it as `id`)

Comment: @OzgurSar I tried this also, no effect. :/

Comment: I didn't understand how many counters are there. You should also fix the increase and decrease functions from `setCounter(counter + 1)` to `setCounter(prev => prev + 1)`

Comment: The problem is that states aren't updated synchronously. When you call setId there is no guarantee that the id is updated soon enough that your item will use the new value.

Comment: You could use `useEffect` to run a side effect after the re-render, but since you have many counters this isn't really a good way of doing it

Comment: The best way (I can think of) right now, is to use a class component and use `this.setState`, you can provide a callback argument to that function to ensure that it gets run after the state was set

Comment: This should work: `let newId = 0; setId(prev => { newId = prev + 1; return prev + 1;});
  setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, { id: newId, name: props.name}])`

Comment: @AjeetShah unfortunately it does not :D

Comment: @MrCodingB I really want to avoid using class components.

Comment: Are you trying to add infinite number of counters and keep track of each's state?

Comment: @OzgurSar I am trying to create unique id's for each element in the context state.

Comment: I posted the other counter's code just to show how it works, and how the id one doesn't. They have nothing else to do with the problem.

Comment: @rllstpwz first do this: `const incCounter = () => { console.log(counter); setCounter(counter + 1); console.log(counter); }`, next take another look at this part here: `const counter` and `const id` do you expect a constant to change value? `setState()` is async! always! even with hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem. I call this component multiple times and I was trying to modify a single value from many places, but since the id was in the component this was impossible. I am sorry for the unprovided information about the multiple call. The solution was to simply use uuidv4 and call it and pass the id as a prop when I create the component itself. This way everything forward is working as expected. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is only a counter or index, you can use `useRef`:

```
const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemsContext)
const id = useRef(0)
```

And increment it and use it in `setItems`:

```
const addItem = () => {
    if (!(items.some(item => item.name === props.name))) {
        setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, { id: ++id.current, name: props.name}])
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing it, still got {current:0} everytime.

Comment: Then, I am sure, there are other hidden problems (or use cases) in your code which we don't see in the question or comments. To fix that, you should consider making a code sandbox.

Comment: In my opinion it is kind of unnecessary since this is the whole component, of course i deleted most of the unneeded jsx (ex: classnames, tags that have nothing to do with the problem) and that's all about it.

Answer (score 0):

The component's state update function run `async`, when you run `setItems`, the id value is `0`, to avoid this, move the setItems to `useEffect` block using `id` as dependency:

```
useEffect(()=> {
   setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, { id: id, name: props.name}])
}, [id])

const addItem = () => {
    if (!(items.some(item => item.name === props.name))) {
        setId(id + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: This interferes with the component where I am displaying the items for some reason and the id is still not updating.